# How to get high resolution time using sparc assembly?

Tags: system-calls, sparc

I use syscall SYS_time, but its resolution is 1 second.
Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try [`clock_gettime(3R)`](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/805-8069/6j7j9vnt1) ([same for Linux](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime)). I have to dig up the assembly version for the calls.